# Не могу понять, как работает передача по ссылке в PHP

Tags: php, документация

В [документации PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.references.pass.php) есть следующий код на тему "Передача по ссылке".

```
function foo(&$var) {
    $var++;
}
function &bar() {
    $a = 5;
    return $a;
}
foo(bar());
?>
```

Абсолютно не могу понять, что делает данный код. Я пытался вывести **$a**, но возникает
уведомление: *Undefined variable*. Может кто-нибудь по пунктам расписать, что происходит в данном коде, пожалуйста?

Comment: `$a` вне области видимости, также `foo` ничего не возвращает. Чтобы получить `$a` сделайте `return $var;` в конце в функции `foo`

Comment: а, не подскажите, какой вообще смысл здесь в этих амперсандах? ведь если их убрать, всё будет то же самое, тот же самый результат на выходе. ну, если только в ```bar()``` добавить ```global $a;```, тогда хоть какой-то смысл появляется.

Comment: за пределами стен учебного заведения или книжек 2000х годов вы использование global вряд ли увидите в коде

Comment: вот тебе пример передачи по ссылке и без https://onlinegdb.com/H1vPBYbwd

Comment: в первом случае при передаче по ссылке функция работает с переменной "напрямую", во втором случае функция копирует значение переменной в свою область видимости, но изменить переменную извне не может.